# Opening a fragment in a Tab Layout

Tags: android, tabs

I have a fragment (AdvertismentFragment) that contains two tabs, now the thing is i need to open in the layout of the first tab a fragment as shown bellow (AdsFragment).. now when i click for the first time the fragment is displayed within the tab and all its content, but when i leave this fragment and return it doesn't display the fragment inside the tab...

here is the code of one of the tabs:

```
public class AdsFragment extends Fragment {

public AdsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ads, container, false);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.attending_layout,EventsFragment.newInstance("all","upcoming")).commit();

    return v;
}

}
```

what should i do then ???

here is the fragment that holds the two tabs:

```
public class AdvertisementFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {


private TabHost tabHost;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private View v;

public AdvertisementFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_advertisement, container, false);
    initViewPager();
    initTabHost();
    return v;
}

/**
 * Initialize the {@link TabHost} {@code tabHost}.
 */
private void initTabHost() {
    tabHost = ((TabHost) v.findViewById(R.id.tabHost));
    tabHost.setup();
    /**
     * {@code tabName} {@link String} will hold the tab names.
     */
    String tabName[] = { "Ads","Videos"};
    for (int i = 0; i < tabName.length; i++) {
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabName[i]);

        tabSpec.setIndicator(tabName[i]);
        tabSpec.setContent(new FakeContent(getActivity()));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
    /**
     * Change the Text color associated with the {@link android.widget.TabWidget}.
     */
    for (int tabIndex = 0; tabIndex < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); tabIndex++) {
        View tab = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabIndex);
        TextView t = (TextView) tab.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1976D2"));
        t.setAllCaps(false);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        t.setTypeface(typeface);
        tab.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apptheme_tab_indicator_holo);
    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String s) {
    int selectedItem = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedItem);

    /**
     * Using {@link HorizontalScrollView} {@code horizontalScrollView}
     * we can display page by page to the user while pressing the tab.
     */
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.h_scroll_view);
    View tabView = tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
    /**
     * Allow the Scroll to be smooth.
     */
    int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (horizontalScrollView.getWidth() - tabView.getWidth() / 2);
    horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
}

/**
 * Create and return the content of each tab created.
 */
public class FakeContent implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {

    private Context context;

    public FakeContent(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Callback to make the tab contents
     *
     * @param tag Which tab was selected.
     * @return The view to display the contents of the selected tab.
     */
    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View fakeView = new View(context);
        fakeView.setMinimumHeight(0);
        fakeView.setMinimumWidth(0);

        return fakeView;
    }
}

private void initViewPager() {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    //viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new AnimationUtilities.DepthPageTransformer());
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragmentList.add(new AdsFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new VideoFragment());
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(((MainActivity)getActivity()).getFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Why you called a new fragment transaction inside onCreateView method before inflating current fragment

Comment: Does AdsFragment contain two tabs? Where are you defining the tab? Can you mention some more code and elaborate a little more.

Comment: i fixed the code, the inflater is now in a View v, and i returned it after i called the fragment. @bryanc

Comment: no AdsFragment is one of the tabs, there is a fragment that holds these two tabs.. @RickSanchez

Comment: If your problem doesn't resolved yet please edit your question and post recent code after changes

Comment: i've edited my code above, and posted the fragment that creates the tabs.. @bryanc

Comment: Please use getChildFragmentManager instead of ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getFragmentManager   in init view pager method

Comment: sorry for the late response.. thank you for your help it works perfectly :) @bryanc